# Best practices, extending classes

Tags: xna, c#, architecture

I'm developing a game in XNA(C#) and I wonder what are the best practices for having different types of pads.
For example I have 2 types of pads:

- Pad that just moves left (decreasing X coordinate)
- Pad moves left and moves up and down (cos function on Y coordinate)

Later I would like to implement more pads. I know I could check type in `Update` method and do a proper method for updating but I think it could be done better.
I have the Pads class:

```
class Pads
    static list of pads;
    public void draw();
    public static void drawAll(); //Iterate through list and draw each item
    public void update();
    public static void updateAll(); //Iterate through list and update each item
```

Should I create another class for example cosPad which would extend Pads?

I really don't have idea how to make everything logical.

Answer (score 6):

If the pads are only different in their movement/behavior I would create a separate class to control this and use composition to get the desired effect.

```
public class Pad : GameObject{
    Vector2 Position;
    Behavior B;

    Update(GameTime t){
        B.Update(this, t);
    }
}

public class Slide : Behavior{
    Update(GameObject o, GameTime t){
        o.Position.X = sin(t);
    }
}

public class Circle : Behavior{
    Update(GameObject o, GameTime t){
        o.Position.X = sin(t);
        o.Position.Y = cos(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand **B.Update(this, t)** What do we put when we are initializing new pad? Behavior B = new Slide()?

Comment: No, more like Pad P = new Pad();  P.B = new Circle(); (ok the naming is a bit akward but you get the point)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract class `Pad` that represents a moveable pad, then your `Pads` class would have a list of these `Pad`s.

The `Pad` class could have an implemented draw method if that was common to both, and an abstract `Update(GameTime)` method.

You'd derive your 2 concrete classes `PadMoveLeft` and `PadCosine` from `Pad` which would implement `Update`.